# List to tuple in Haskell

Tags: haskell

let's say i have a list like this:

```
["Questions", "that", "may", "already", "have", "your", "correct", "answer"]
```

and want to have this:

```
[("Questions","that"),("may","already"),("have","your"),("correct","answer")]
```

can this be done ? or is it a bad Haskell practice ?

Comment: What should happen if there is an odd number of elements?

Comment: in this case, there is always an even number of elements @user5402

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to do it, with the help of a helper function that lets you drop every second element from your target list, and then just use `zip`. This may not have your desired behavior when the list is of odd length since that's not yet defined in the question.

```
-- This is just from ghci

let my_list = ["Questions", "that", "may", "already", "have", "your", "correct", "answer"]

let dropEvery [] _ = []
let dropEvery list count = (take (count-1) list) ++ dropEvery (drop count list) count

zip (dropEvery my_list 2) $ dropEvery (tail my_list) 2

[("Questions","that"),("may","already"),("have","your"),("correct","answer")
```

The helper function is taken from question #6 from [99 Questions.](https://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/99_questions/11_to_20), where there are *many* other implementations of the same idea, probably many with better recursion optimization properties.

To understand `dropEvery`, it's good to remember what `take` and `drop` each do. `take k some_list` takes the first `k` entries of `some_list`. Meanwhile `drop k some_list` drops the first `k` entries.

If we want to drop every Nth element, it means we want to keep each run of (N-1) elements, then drop one, then do the same thing again until we are done.

The first part of `dropEvery` does this: it `take`s the first `count-1` entries, which it will then concatenate to whatever it gets from the rest of the list.

After that, it says `drop count` (forget about the N-1 you kept, and also the 1 (in the Nth spot) that you had wanted to drop all along) -- and after these are dropped, you can just recursively apply the same logic to whatever is leftover.

Using `++` in this manner can be quite expensive in Haskell, so from a performance point of view this is not so great, but it was one of the shorter implementations available at that 99 questions page.

Here's a function to do it all in one shot, which is maybe a bit more readable:

```
byTwos :: [a] -> [(a,a)]
byTwos [] = []
byTwos xs = zip firsts seconds 
    where enumerated = zip xs [1..]
          firsts     = [fst x | x <- enumerated, odd $ snd x]
          seconds    = [fst x | x <- enumerated, even $ snd x]
```

In this case, I started out by saying this problem will be easy to solve with `zip` if I just already had the list of odd-indexed elements and the list of even-indexed elements. So let me just write that down, and then worry about getting them in some `where` clause.

In the `where` clause, I say first `zip xs [1..]` which will make `[("Questions", 1), ("that", 2), ...]` and so on.

Side note: recall that `fst` takes the first element of a tuple, and `snd` takes the second element.

Then `firsts` says take the first element of all these values **if** the second element is odd -- these will serve as "firsts" in the final output tuples from `zip`.

`seconds` says do the same thing, but only **if** the second element is even -- these will serve as "seconds" in the final output tuples from `zip`.

In case the list has odd length, `firsts` will be one element longer than `seconds` and so the final `zip` means that the final element of the list will simply be dropped, and the result will be the same as though you called the function on the front of the list (all but final element).

Comment: could you elaborate that into a cleaner and single function ? because that is really confusing for me

Comment: Could you just explain the last function in a little detail ? i'm not sure i entirely get what you're doing there...

Comment: I cleaned it up a bit and used comprehensions instead of `map` and `filter` which I think is easier to read.

Comment: Pattern matching is IMHO the right way.. But I'm new here.

Comment: @prpl.mnky.dshwshr I couldn't even try. I glimpsed at `(take (count-1) list) ++ dropEvery (drop count list) count` and that was a huge turn down for me.

Comment: @prpl.mnky.dshwshr I've read it now and I didn't change my mind at all. It seems like you worked around the assumption that you had to use `zip`. The fun fact is that when I was thinking of an answer I went down the same path as you did. But then I saw Johannes Kuhn's answer and his answer is: 1) very simple; 2) easy to manage non even lists; 3) efficient; 4) short. There's not 1 of these points for which any of your solutions are better. Not even one. I'm sorry, but this shouldn't be the accepted answer. Not for the points, but from the technical point of view.

Comment: @prpl.mnky.dshwshr Oh damnit it. It's almost 4am in the morning. How did this happen. ;)

Answer (score 4):

For a simple method (that fails for a odd number of elements) you can use

```
combine :: [a] -> [(a, a)]
combine (x1:x2:xs) = (x1,x2):combine xs
combine (_:_) = error "Odd number of elements"
combine [] = []
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a30099019c2e39a3)

Or you could use some complex method like in an other answer that I don't really want to understand.

More generic:

```
map2 :: (a -> a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
map2 f (x1:x2:xs) = (f x1 x2) : map2 f xs
map2 _ (_:_) = error "Odd number of elements"
map2 _ [] = []
```

Comment: Interesting functionality. with the live demo

Comment: While this is very concise, one of my goals was to explicitly avoid pattern matching `x:y:xs` because pattern match error on odd-length lists is too much of a pain for me, and the helper functions are pretty easy to avoid it.

Comment: I don't see the problem.

Comment: @prpl.mnky.dshwshr You can create your own error just as easily by pattern matching on `combine (_:[]) = ...`.

Comment: I didn't say there was a problem. I said my goal was to avoid this because, for me, the pattern match error is not OK. If it is OK for you, then here is your answer.

Comment: @prpl.mnky.dshwshr You don't need to have a pattern match error. v0v

Comment: But what if you want it to behave like `zip` and just apply to everything but the final element. Then this too starts involving convoluted stuff.

Comment: @prpl.mnky.dshwshr If you want to discard the last single element you just need: `combine (_:[]) = []`.

Comment: meh, 1 pattern will fail if there are not at least 2 elements in the list. 2nd pattern will match if there is at least 1 element in the list. return `[]` there and you have zip like behavior.

Answer (score 1):

A simple pattern matching could do the trick :

```
f [] = []
f (x:y:xs) = (x,y):f(xs)
```

It means that an empty list gives an empty list, and that a list of a least two elements returns you a list with a couple of these two elements and then application of the same reasoning with what follows...

Answer (score 0):

Using `chunk` from `Data.List.Split` you can get the desired result of pairing every two consecutive items in a list, namely for the given list named by `xs`,

```
import Data.List.Split

map (\ys -> (ys!!0, ys!!1)) $ chunk 2 xs
```

This solution assumes the given list has an even number of items.